# call RowDataBound from another function

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a 2 Gridviews. The first grid has a button that when clicked it will populate a second grid with the data based on the id of the button clicked.

I then have code in the RowDataBound function to show the grid based on the row selected. But the problem is the code is automatically running the RowDataBound before the populate function. So the second grid isn't displaying.

Code for GridView:

```
<asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRT" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRT_RowDataBound"  
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged"                           
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        DataKeyNames="ChecklistID"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistID" HeaderText="ID"  ></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" HeaderText="Select" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistDate" HeaderText="Checklist Date" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" ></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Note" ></asp:BoundField>

                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void gvCVRT_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        lookupCVRT work = (lookupCVRT)e.Row.DataItem;
        GridView gv = sender as GridView;

        if (work.ID != null)
        {
            int index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("Select");
            if (index > -1)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[index].Attributes.Add("class", "gvCVRTRow");
                e.Row.Cells[index].ToolTip = "Click here to Edit Checklist";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for select button:

```
protected void gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<lookupCVRT> workDetails = lookupCVRT.GetChecklistItemsByChecklistID(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString(), gvCVRT.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
    gvCVRTDetails.DataSource = workDetails;
    gvCVRTDetails.DataBind();
    FireJavascriptCallback("setArgAndPostBack ();");
}
```

So the problem is when I click on the Select button in the grid it runs the `RowDataBound` first then the `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` but I need to run `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` first. Can I call the `RowDataBound` function from `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Page_Load function:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetChecklistID = "";
            if (ParentID.HasValue)
            {
                ViewState["ParentID"] = ParentID;

                List<lookupCVRT> work = lookupCVRT.GetCVRTItems(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString());
                ViewState["CVRT"] = work;
                gvCVRT.DataSource = work;
                gvCVRT.DataBind();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ViewState["ParentID"] != null)
            {
                ParentID = (int?)ViewState["ParentID"];
                List<lookupCVRT> work = ViewState["CVRT"] as List<lookupCVRT>;
                gvCVRT.DataSource = work;
                gvCVRT.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your Page_Load method and all other methods that contain a fall to DataBind()?

Comment: @Markus add Page_Load code to my question. This is the only place DataBind is called. When I click on select it goes into the `else` part of the method

Comment: thanks; I think I've identified the problem; please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Markus ok I've updated my code but the same thing is still happening. It runs the `OnRowDataBound ` first then goes to the `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` function

Comment: can you trace the code in a debugger? Set a breakpoint on each call to `DataBind` you find. `RowDataBound` is called as a result to a call to `DataBind`.

Comment: @Markus the only place the `DataBind` is called is from the `Page_Load`.

Comment: @Markus I realize this question has become very confusing. With your help I have narrowed down the problem. I have created another question that hopefully better explains this issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577768/call-onselectedindexchanged-from-gridview-before-other-function

Answer (score 1):

The `OnRowDataBound` event is only called if the `DataBind` method for the `GridView` has been called.

In your specific case, the problem is in `Page_Load` in the `else` branch of the `Page.IsPostBack` condition:

```
 else
{
    if (ViewState["ParentID"] != null)
    {
        ParentID = (int?)ViewState["ParentID"];
        List<lookupCVRT> work = ViewState["CVRT"] as List<lookupCVRT>;
        gvCVRT.DataSource = work;
        gvCVRT.DataBind();

    }
}
```

This code is run for each postback. Unless you reset `ViewState["ParentID"]` somewhere else in your code, on every postback you bind the GridView `gvCVRT` again. This is the reason that `RowDataBound` is called. After finishing `Page_Load`, the page calls the additional event handlers, in your case `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged`.

In order to solve this problem, you need to change the code in your `Page_Load` handler so that there are no calls to `DataBind` for a postback:

```
// field moved to class level so that you can access this variable instead of a DataRow in gvCVRT
private List<lookupCVRT> work;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GetChecklistID = "";
        if (ParentID.HasValue)
        {
            ViewState["ParentID"] = ParentID;

            work = lookupCVRT.GetCVRTItems(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString());
            ViewState["CVRT"] = work;
            gvCVRT.DataSource = work;
            gvCVRT.DataBind();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (ViewState["ParentID"] != null)
        {
            ParentID = (int?)ViewState["ParentID"];
            work = ViewState["CVRT"] as List<lookupCVRT>;
        }
    }
}
```

The root cause of your problem is that you need the data in a postback request and that you put these into `ViewState["CVRT"]` instead of requesting the data anew. In web applications it is pretty common the read the data again for a new request. So you might think about whether you really need to put the data into ViewState or whether you can request them upon a postback from the data source.

Putting the data into ViewState increases the size of the page that is transferred to the client (basically you have the HTML for the GridView and in addition you have the data in ViewState). So requesting them anew would be the better way in most cases.

Comment: But the `Gridview` gets bound when select is clicked, because I need to get the ID from the row selected: `gvCVRT.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString()`. I can't do this from the page_load because I don't have the ID yet.

Comment: @user123456789: Yes, I understand that. I've read your question again and I'm more and more confused by the names of the controls and the event handlers. To clarify: you have a GridView `gvCVRT` that is the parent with event handlers `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` and `gvCVRT_RowDataBound`. Then there is a child GridView `gvCVRTDetails`, but there are not mentions of event handlers for the child GridView in the question. With `RowDataBound` you mean `gvCVRT_RowDataBound` or a handler for the child GridView?

Comment: @user123456789: however, `RowDataBound` is only run after a call to `DataBind`. So it would be a good step to check all calls to `DataBind` in your code and if they are at the right spot. If the parent GridView for instance is data-bound in `Page_Load`, its `gvCVRT_RowDataBound` will run before `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` and most likely destroy the selection.

Comment: yes the parent GridView is data-bound in the `Page_Load`. When the select is clicked from the parent GridView it runs the `RowDataBound` again then runs `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged `. But I need to run `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` first to bind the grid before it tries to display it

Comment: @user123456789 In `Page_Load` is there a check for `Page.IsPostBack` around the call to `gvCVRT.DataBind()` similar to the one in my answer? If not, then `gvCVRT` is data-bound for each request in `Page_Load`. As `DataBind()` is called in `Page_Load`, `gvCVRT_RowDataBound` runs before any other events are processed, thus also before `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: Yes the a way to run `gvCVRT_RowDataBound` after `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you preferred to use `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` then `grdParent_RowDataBound` ... i have created a simple solution for you .. it could help you ..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div>
        <label>Parent Grid</label>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdParent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            DataKeyField="Id" OnRowDataBound="grdParent_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="grdParent_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />                
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Details"  HeaderText="Select" Text="Hello" ButtonType="Link" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div>
         <label>child Grid</label>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdChild" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            DataKeyNames="ChildId" OnRowDataBound="grdChild_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Roll" />                
                <asp:ImageField HeaderText="Image" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Codebehind**

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<ParentClass> pList = new List<ParentClass>()
            {
                new ParentClass{Id=5, Name="V"},
                new ParentClass{Id=6,Name="VI"},
                new ParentClass{Id=7,Name="VII"},
                new ParentClass{Id=8,Name="VIII"},
                new ParentClass{Id=9,Name="IX"},
                new ParentClass{Id=10,Name="X"},
            };

            grdParent.DataSource = pList;
            grdParent.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void grdParent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem == null || e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            return;
        }

        ParentClass p = e.Row.DataItem as ParentClass;

        var btn = e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        btn.CommandArgument = p.Id.ToString();
    }

    protected void grdParent_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int parentId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        var releventStudents = GetRepositary().FindAll(i => i.ParentId == parentId);

        grdChild.DataSource = releventStudents;
        grdChild.DataBind();

    }

    protected void grdChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem == null || e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            return;
        }

        //lookupCVRT work = (lookupCVRT)e.Row.DataItem;
        //GridView gv = sender as GridView;

        //if (work.ID != null)
        //{
        //    int index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("Select");
        //    if (index > -1)
        //    {
        //        e.Row.Cells[index].Attributes.Add("class", "gvCVRTRow");
        //        e.Row.Cells[index].ToolTip = "Click here to Edit Checklist";
        //    }
        //}         
    }

    private List<ChildClass> GetRepositary()
    {
        List<ChildClass> allChild = new List<ChildClass>();
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            ChildClass c = new ChildClass
            {
                ChildId = i,
                ParentId = r.Next(5, 10),
                Name = "Child Name " + i,
                Roll = i
            };

            allChild.Add(c);
        }

        return allChild;
    }
}

public class ParentClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int Roll { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```