# call OnSelectedIndexChanged from GridView before other function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have two GridViews. The user can select a row from the first GridView and a list based on the GridView ID selected will display.

First Grid:
[image]

Second Grid:
[image]

Code for first GridView:

```
<asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRT" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged"   
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRT_RowDataBound"                          
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        DataKeyNames="ChecklistID"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistID" HeaderText="ID"  ></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" HeaderText="Select" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistDate" HeaderText="Checklist Date" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" ></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Note" ></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-CssClass="tblRowDelete">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete"
                                                runat="server" OnClientClick="event.stopPropagation()" OnClick="btnDeleteCVRT_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void gvCVRT_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            lookupCVRT work = (lookupCVRT)e.Row.DataItem;
            GridView gv = sender as GridView;

            string checklistid = work.ChecklistID.ToString();

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("ID", "gvCVRT_" + work.ID);
            LinkButton btnDelete = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
            btnDelete.CommandArgument = checklistid;

            if (work.ID != null)
            {
                int index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("Select");
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[index].Attributes.Add("class", "gvCVRTRow");
                    e.Row.Cells[index].ToolTip = "Click here to Edit Checklist";
                    e.Row.Cells[index].Attributes.Add("style", "color:blue;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
protected void gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       List<lookupCVRT> workDetails = lookupCVRT.GetChecklistItemsByChecklistID(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString(), gvCVRT.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
        gvCVRTDetails.DataSource = workDetails;
        gvCVRTDetails.DataBind();
        FireJavascriptCallback("setArgAndPostBack ();");
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$(".gvCVRTRow").off();
        $(".gvCVRTRow").click(function (e) {
            ShowAddEditCVRT(this, "Edit");
        });

function ShowAddEditCVRT(sender, AddEdit) {
        $("#divCVRTDetails").fadeIn(300); 
}
```

Sorry its a lot of code but I wanted to show exactly what is happening. When I set the code to `int index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("Select");` it goes into the javascript function `ShowAddEditCVRT` first, which tries to display the second grid `divCVRTDetails`. But I need to run the method `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` first because this binds the second grid with the ID selected from the first grid.

The only way I can get the second grid to bind first is to change the code to this: `int index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("Checklist Date");`.
So the user has to click on select first (to bind the grid) then click on the date cell to display the grid.

so my question is, is there anyway to run the `gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged` method before the javascript function gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this is I called the javascript by using `FireJavascriptCallback("myFunction();");` then just put the javascript code I needed into this function.

`FireJavascriptCallback` is a function:

```
 protected void FireJavascriptCallback(string JSFunctionName)
    {
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Callback", JSFunctionName, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the link below for more detail where I found this information.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/246366/run-javascript-from-side-server-in-asp-net-and-csh

You can add your javascript from the server side after you bind your gridview.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    {
    String script = @"<script language=""Javascript"">
                    $(".gvCVRTRow").off();
                    $(".gvCVRTRow").click(function (e) {
                         ShowAddEditCVRT(this, "Edit");
                    });

                    function ShowAddEditCVRT(sender, AddEdit) {
                        $("#divCVRTDetails").fadeIn(300); 
                    }
                 </script>";
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("experiment", script);
    gvCVRT.Attributes.Add("DataBound", "TestJScript()");
```

I believe this replaces your FireJavascriptCallback("setArgAndPostBack ();");

**EDIT**
I changed the code to better match what you provided and also where to put the code. I think it should go under page load. I also changed the gvCVRT.Attributes.Add to make it so the javascript runs when the gvCVRT is databound.

Comment: That's odd, using the generic testing form of this located on the link I gave worked for me. Did you copy and paste directly from what I posted? Also, are you getting the error at runtime?

Comment: yes I copied and pasted directly from your code. First I was getting the errors Error `Newline in constant` and `; expected` so I moved everything onto the one line. But I'm still getting errors for `$(".gvCVRTRow")` and  "Edit", and any part that is using " "
`

Comment: So far I haven't been able to find the issue, would it be easier if the functioanlality your javascript is calling was instead done in C# and then called by a JavaScript function? Take a look at this link. [Calling a code-behind function from JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180355/Calling-a-code-behind-function-from-JavaScript)

Comment: @user123456789 Another thing you can try is replacing all of the double quotes within the javascript with single quotes since js treats them the same(mostly).

Comment: @user123456789 Where does FireJavascriptCallback() live? I have been trying to google it and can't find it. Also, isn't your answer what you were already doing? (I don't have enough rep to comment under your answer.)

Comment: Added the code for FireJavascriptCallback()  to my answer. Yes it was what I was doing already. I realized I could use FireJavascriptCallback to call the javascript I needed